# python: convert string to regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using python to do some text comparison. The text format is like `44=100`. 
Let's say, I have 2 text, `44=100` and `44=3001`. I call the string on the left of `=` is tag, right is value. 
 Now I need to compare the tag and value for them. The tag must be the same, `44` equals `44`, but the values don't have to, as long as its format is the same. ie. `100` and `3001` are in the same format(normal digits). But `1.0E+7` in `44=1.0E+7` is different. 
tThe point is on value comparison. ie. I write a script comp.py, when I run `comp.py 2000 30010`, I will get output `true`; while I run `comp.py 100000 1.0E+8`, output is `false`. How can I do it? I am thinking about converting the value into an regular expression and comparing it with other.

pseudo code:

```
rex1 = '100000'.getRegrex(), rex2 = '1.0E+8'.getRegrex(), rex1.compare(rex2)
```

Is it a feasible way? any advice?

Comment: your explanation is rather dim, can you make a list of inputs and wanted output?

Comment: sorry for my requirement. the point is on value comparison. ie. i write a script comp.py, when i run comp.py 2000 30010, i will get output 'true'; while i run comp.py 100000 1.0E+8, output is 'false'. can we do it?  posudo code: rex1 = '100000'.getRegrex(), rex2 = '1.0E+8'.getRegrex(), rex1.compare(rex2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rex1 = '100000'.getRegrex(), rex2 = '1.0E+8'.getRegrex(), rex1.compare(rex2)

Your approach is wrong. It is not only difficult but also illogical to "deduce" a regexp from a given string. What you would do is:

- Define your types. With each type you would have a corresponding regexp.
- Compare your input text against all your defined types and check which type it is of.
- Compare the two types.

Comment: hi Thrustmaster. can't we generate an regular expression from any given string? if it has to be pre-defined, then i probably need to create a dictionary for all tags...

Comment: @user462872: Yes, thats what I meant. You would need to create a dict for regexps.

Comment: Thank you, Thrustmaster.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your idea of `rex1 = '100000'.getRegrex()` could be done

```
rex1 = re.compile('10000')
```

But as Thustmaster pointed out, you may want to define the regular expression with more abstraction of the pattern of your data.

Comment: This does not help solve the stated problem; the regex for `10000` will only match `10000` and no other strings.